# How can I print out the corresponding exam score of the predicted model, with the corresponding gaming hours using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, prediction

**This is my code, i would like to find the corresponding exam score for 5.9hrs, 5.5 hrs, 4.7hrs, 4.2hrs. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!!** *(I have thought for many hours but I still cant figure it out? Can someone help me, Great thanks to you who have read this questions.)*

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gametime = np.array([4.6, 4.9, 7, 1.7, 5.6, 1.2, 0.1, 7.9, 5.2, 3.4, 4.2, 0.1, 4.7, 1.9, 3.4, 4.8, 5.2, 1.5, 1, 7], dtype=float)

examscore = np.array([44, 43, 2, 79, 21, 83, 78, 3, 31, 44, 38, 83, 47, 69, 49, 34, 34, 68, 78, 8], dtype=float)

plt.scatter(gametime, examscore)
plt.show()

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

# build model network with single neuron that takes one input
model = Sequential([Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')


# train the network with data for lots of times
# (add verbose=0 to suppress training outputs)
model.fit(gametime/24, examscore/100, epochs=8000)

model.predict( [ 1 ] ) # requires x in range 0 - 1

# show predictions (line)
plt.plot(gametime, examscore, 'ro', label = 'original')
scorepredict = model.predict(gametime/24)*100
plt.plot(gametime, scorepredict , label = 'predict')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# show w and b
[[w]], [b] = model.layers[0].get_weights()
print( f"Learned parameters: w = {w}, b = {b}")

timedata1 = np.array([5.9, 5.5, 4.7, 4.2, 1.1])
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.predict` to do this.

```
y_pred = model.predict(timedata1)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: This is not really working.

Comment: @hlohdfklsakjsdf what error do you get? or what output are you getting?